# Possible to make custom role in multisite that can add sites?

Tags: multisite, capabilities, user-roles

I am creating a network on MultiSite, and am wanting to keep the Super Admin privileges very tightly locked. This setup is hosed on WPengine, and they add their plugin in the dashboard that shows the super admin a menu area that gets access to some server stuff, I obviously want that blocked from folks who may go poking around.

I am using the Premium version of the plugin [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) to create a custom role, call it "Sub Admin".

I am trying to find out, if it is possible, to give this role the ability to add new sites?

I have added the `manage_sites` capability, but the *Add Site* menu item is not showing up. I tried also adding capabilities for `manage_network` and `manage_network_options` to test if they were somehow requisite, but no.

Has anyone done this, or know if it is possible? Or do I have to bite the bullet and dish out super admin rights?

Answer (score 1):

From a quick glans at 3.7 code it seems that the "Add Site" menu is accessible only to users with "create_sites" capability

Comment: Thank you.I tried adding that capability as well, but menu is still not visible. Any other thoughts? :)